# ASP.NET MVC 2 strongly typed htmlhelper, indexes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
public class Foo { public bool Checked {get;set;}}
```

View:

```
<viewdata model="Foo[] fooList" />
<for each="var f in fooList">
    ${Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x[fIndex].Checked)}
</for>
```

Will output:

```
<input id="Checked" name="Checked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Checked" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input id="Checked" name="Checked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Checked" type="hidden" value="false" />

<input id="Checked" name="Checked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Checked" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Problem is that `System.Web.Mvc.ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` does not include index in id/name.

That leads to problems in case I want to add a label for every checkbox (because all id`s are the same).

Any ideas how to handle this properly?

---

From the MVC source=>

```
 while (part != null) {
            if (part.NodeType == System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
                MemberExpression memberExpressionPart = (MemberExpression)part;
                nameParts.Push(memberExpressionPart.Member.Name);
                part = memberExpressionPart.Expression;
            }
            else {
                //arghhhh... [index] != MemberAccess :(
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability of the expression-based helpers to understand indexes isn't in the product yet.  It will be in the next preview release (whatever comes after MVC 2 RC).  See http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4970.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CheckBoxFor overload that allows you to specify html attributes:

```
CheckBoxFor(TModel)(HtmlHelper(TModel), Expression(Func(TModel, Boolean)), IDictionary(String, Object))
```

For example,

```
${Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[fIndex].Checked, new { id = "foo" + fIndex) })}
```

Comment: That's not **properly**. In this case - let me ask what's the benefit of `CheckBoxFor` 'strongly-typed' helper method if i won't be able to get that id back from view model without messing around with hard-coded strings? That's the same as to use `${Html.CheckBox("foo"+fIndex,m.AllCatalogs[i].Checked)}` which even looks better.