# Null Values returned to Controller for Edit action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following actions in my controller.  The first (top) `Edit` works fine and serves the correct values.  However, in the second one, i.e. the 'return' `Edit`, every property of model is at default value, i.e. null for ref types and zero for value types.  I have examined the HTTP post data and it has all the properties correctly named and with correct values.  What could be wrong?

**Controller excerpt:**

```
        [Authorize(Order = 0, Roles = "Requester, Controller")]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            JobCardViewData viewData = ViewDataFactory.CreateBaseViewData<JobCardViewData>("Installation Details");
            viewData.JobCard = new JobCardService().GetById(id);
            return View(viewData);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(JobCard model)
        {
            try
            {
                new JobCardService().Update(model);
                var x = RedirectToAction("Index");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = model.InstallationNumber});
            }
        }
```

**View excerpt:**

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobCard.Name) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobCard.Name) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobCard.Name) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobCard.Surname) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobCard.Surname) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobCard.Surname) %>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe just show what the generated HTML looks like?  And maybe what the model looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this answer from Phil [Using ViewModel Pattern with MVC 2 Strongly Typed HTML Helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160171/using-viewmodel-pattern-with-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers/2172756#2172756)

*When you use the strongly typed helpers against the type, the helpers create form fields assuming that's the type you're posting to. When the types don't match up, there's a problem.*

In this case, the type being posted to (`JobCard`) is different to the type the view originally was created against(`JobCardViewData`).

Try changing the method signature to the ffg and I am almost certain the `JobCard` values will be populated within the model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(JobCardViewData model)
{ ... }
```

Phil presents two approaches which can be used to resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494940/custom-viewmodel-with-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers-return-null-object-on-cre/2500327#2500327

Comment: Ha! You're exactly right. I stared at that code for about 15 minutes and I didn't see it. The data is getting to the server, but it's not in a format that can automatically bind to the parameter in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you examine the contents of the raw HTTP POST using Fiddler (or anything else) and confirm the values are actually getting sent to the web server? Is this a problem of getting values to the server or binding the values to your object?

Comment: You are the second person to recommend that, I will try it shortly, thanks, but regards the binding, I'm using 'TextBoxFor', not the 'Bind' method, so I have no idea if the problem is with binding.

Comment: please see my edits.  The post (using Firebug) contains all correct data.